# NoClassDefFoundError during runtime on application built with sbt

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have the following **build.sbt** file:

```
lazy val shared = (project in file("shared")) .
  settings (moduleName := "x-shared") .
  ...

lazy val service = (project in file ("service")) .
  settings (moduleName := "x-api") .
  dependsOn (shared % "compile->compile;test->test", job % "compile->compile;test->test") .
  aggregate (shared, joob) .
  ...

lazy val job = (project in file("job") dependsOn (shared % "compile->compile;test->test")) .
  settings (moduleName := "x-job") .
  ...
```

The service submodule requires both **shared** and **job** modules. The shared project is basically a set of classes used by all the modules. Both job and service are different applications, but we have an endpoint on the service, that requires to start the job application.

The problem is that on runtime, we get the following error when trying to reference the **job** module classes:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/earnest/ingestor/models/Pipeline$
```

But we are able to reference the shared module without any problem.

The folder structure of the project is the following:

```
./root
  ./service
  ./shared
  ./job
```

One thing I notice is that the jar file generated for the **job** module, does not get copied on the  lib folders on the service module, in difference with the **shared** jar file:

*service/target/universal/stage/lib* dir contains both:

```
com.earnest.x-api-localdev.9288.jar
com.earnest.x-shared-localdev.9288.jar
```

But the **job** jar gets populated to the jobs module:

*job/target/universal/stage/lib* contains:

```
com.earnest.x-job-localdev.9288.jar
```

I'm pretty new to sbt builds, so not sure if might be missing some piece during the build which is done via the sbt clean command. We are using the **sbt-native-package** plugin. I'm not sure what other information might be useful to share so I extracted the build.sbt key points, thanks for the help in advance.

sbt plugins:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.9.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.11")
```

**Update 1**

The application is being launch from a launcher.jar using what it seems to be the LauncherJarPlugin from the build.sbt file. One thing I've notice is that the launcher.jar does not contain the `com.earnest.x-job-localdev.9288.jar` in the ClassPath on `META_INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: Which build command did you use? `sbt-native-packager` is usually not used to produce an uberjar. For that `sbt-assembly` is normally used.

Comment: I'm using the `sbt clean <module>` command, not sure how is it configure but this command is building the complete project.

Another thing I've notice is that the application is run via a launcher.jar, I see we are using the LauncherJarPlugin in the build.sbt as well, which if extracted using the`jar xf` command, the `META_INF/MANIFEST.MF` does not include `com.earnest.x-job-localdev.9288.jar` in the classpath.

Comment: Without details about configuration I doubt we will be able to figure this out.

Comment: Should I share just the complete build.sbt file? I just do not wanted to copy paste that whole block.

Comment: Copy paste anything related to building logic.

Comment: I was able to fix the error by adding `job % "compile->compile;test->test"` the jar now gets added and referenced on the classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue with setting up the service module adding `job % "compile->compile;test->test"`

The whole block looks like:

```
lazy val service = (project in file ("service")) .
  settings (moduleName := "x-api") .
  dependsOn (shared % "compile->compile;test->test", job % "compile->compile;runtime->runtime;test->test") .
  aggregate (shared, job) .
  ...
```